# Sent ETH to wrong address

Tags: transactions

I sent my ETH to this account: 0x11348A2b2bfCbc698d81b7eCA4914f05B21A6Fd3
From my account at: 0x5aD5b7B9AE09EeCd247ae5Bc4ca4A5950D33f716

It's still in this account as I can see it when I go to Etherscan but I don't know where I sent it.

If you say I can contact this person, how do I do that? I thought I put in an address for my Nano X but guess I didn't since it transferred into the Nano x and then out again and the balance is not there.

Transaction ID:
0x0eb0066193f16ebc3c82c25cb1fb39c45c7922c83ef4bba6a371cf9f4e9bd776

Thank you

Comment: most likely you will never contact them

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any universal way to contact an address.

What is sometimes done is sending a transaction, which includes your message, to the address. But that requires for the receiver to: 1) notice the transaction 2) understand to decode it.